# Filtering disconnected nodes in vis.js

Tags: vis.js

I've got a network backed by DataSets containing my nodes and edges.  The edges are weighted, and I want to add the ability to hide edges, and their corresponding nodes, that fall below some threshold.  I can easily filter the edges using a DataView, but want to know how to find nodes that no longer have an edge associated with them and hide them as well. Any  hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually figured out a slick way to do it.  After I update the edgeView as described above, I do this:

```
    nodeView = new vis.DataView(nodes, {
        filter: function(node) {
            connEdges = edgeView.get({
                filter: function(edge) {
                    return(
                        (edge.to == node.id) || (edge.from == node.id));
                }});
            return connEdges.length > 0;
        }
    });
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to loop over the nodes, and for each node, loop over all edges to see if there is at least one edge which has this node's `id` as it's `from` or `to` property.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wound up doing.  I was hoping to do something more slick.  I tried using network.getConnectedNodes() but got no joy.

Comment: maybe the following example can help for inspiration: http://visjs.org/examples/network/exampleApplications/neighbourhoodHighlight.html

Comment: Jos de Jong, that didn't really help. I was looking for a method that didn't involve looping over all of the nodes, which I found, below.  I had actually used that to inform a different function in my code, though.